# Tracing the classical reasoner in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle, isabelle-hol, classical-logic

Some time ago I asked this question on Stack Overflow but got no answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60521384/tracing-tactics-in-isabelle

Section 9.4 The Classical Reasoner of the Isar Reference Manual writes:

> The tactics can be traced, and their components can be called
> directly; in this manner, any proof can be viewed interactively.

I have found sections in this manual about tracing the simplifier and higher order unification.

How can I trace the classical reasoner?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I recall there is [no end-user method to trace the classical reasoner](https://lists.cam.ac.uk/sympa/arc/cl-isabelle-users/2013-10/msg00098.html), but there is a diagnosis configuration.

You should add a line `setup "Config.put_global Blast.trace true"` and further uses of `blast` will output the a (rather verbose) trace-like report.

I believe that you can combine this with a judicious use of `declare [[blast_depth_limit=n]]` with an appropriate non-negative `n` to  dissect the output.